# jquery.min file conflict while making responsive page

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I'm using two jQuery files on my site: jQuery.min file in header page, and jQuery-1.10.1.min on a products page that contains lightboxes for an image gallery.

If I delete jQuery.min file from header, then the header disappears when using a responsive design, but if I delete jQuery-1.10.1.min then the lightboxes no longer work.

Comment: Why two versions of jQuery in the first place?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the question?

Comment: Check `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Refer to this Jquery page for more details about `jQuery.noConflict()` and where to use it. **REF:https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/**

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery-1.10.1.min in header and delete jquery.min.

If its not working, put `$.noConflict();` before including second one.

Comment: where to write $.noConflict().?? in which file??

Comment: On that page where you are including jQuery-1.10.1.min.
I think its your products page.
Put <script type="text/javascript"> $.noConflict(); </script>

Comment: another problem is, header is disappear when window size is less than 400px while making responsive site..